# PLM: Cannot add dummy variable

Tags: r, panel-data, plm

I am currently working on estimating a fixed-effect model using `plm()`. The following table is an example of my data (please note that I used arbitrary numbers here). I ran the regression using district and year fixed-effect, and as expected, there was an error due to the duplication id-time. I, thus, merged district with grade together to obtain a unique id for the regression.

| state | district | year | grade | Y | X | id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AK | 1001 | 2009 | 3 | 0.1 | 0.5 | 1001.3 |
| AK | 1001 | 2010 | 3 | 0.8 | 0.4 | 1001.3 |
| AK | 1001 | 2011 | 3 | 0.5 | 0.7 | 1001.3 |
| AK | 1001 | 2009 | 4 | 1.5 | 1.3 | 1001.4 |
| AK | 1001 | 2010 | 4 | 1.1 | 0.7 | 1001.4 |
| AK | 1001 | 2011 | 4 | 2.1 | 0.4 | 1001.4 |
| ... | ... | ... | .. | .. | .. | ... |
| WY | 5606 | 2011 | 6 | 4.2 | 5.3 | 5606.6 |

Everything went pretty well until I tried to add grade-level dummy variables in the regression. I tried with both `factor()` and added the dummy variables in the equation. But both did not work out. I did not see the dummy variables in my results. Note that I showed only the first work with `factor()` for the sake of conciseness. In the second regression, I generated grade-level dummy variables, i.e., g3 and g4, and put them in the regression instead of `factor(grade)`. It should look like `plm(formula = Y ~ X + g3 + g4,...`.

```
fe <- plm(formula = Y ~ X + factor(grade),
      data = df,
      index = c("id", "year"),
      model = "within",
      effect = "twoways")
summary(fe)

Twoways effects Within Model
Call:
plm(formula = Y ~ X + factor(grade), data = df, 
effect = "twoways", model = "within", index = c("id", 
    "year"))
Unbalanced Panel: n = 64302, T = 1-10, N = 499112
Residuals:
Min.   1st Qu.    Median   3rd Qu.      Max. 
-11.35455  -0.34340   0.00000   0.34364   6.42513 
Coefficients:
   Estimate Std. Error t-value  Pr(>|t|)    
Y 0.0126717  0.0036019   3.518 0.0004348 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
Total Sum of Squares:    173290
Residual Sum of Squares: 173280
R-Squared:      2.8464e-05
Adj. R-Squared: -0.14788
F-statistic: 12.3766 on 1 and 434800 DF, p-value: 0.00043478
```

***Question:*** Why did it happen? Was it because of combining between district and id? If so, how should I fix it to get the coefficients of these dummy variables? Is `plm()` a appropriate package that I should use? Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you!

P.S. It is definitely not a problem of multicollinearity. [This post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/24680/panel-data-model-estimation-with-dummy-variables) said that it was related to this problem. I followed this post, but I got `false` for my results.

Comment: Try `plm::detect.lindep(fe)` to check if this is linear dependence after the FE transformation. Have a look at `?plm::detect.lindep` to better understand the term linear dependence after FE transformation.

Comment: @Helix123 Thanks for your suggestion. I tried this function, but it did not work in my case. I think the function checked only the collinearity on the RHS (i.e., fact 1 + fact 2). However, the regression automatically dropped all of these variables in the model, and it reported: "No linear dependent column(s) detected."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Despite the test you point to, this is definitely a collinearity problem.  There is no independent information in `grade` that is not already accounted for by `id`.  Here's a simple example.  In this model, the only variable is the `id` factor - which is essentially estimating the mean of `y` for each value of `grade` which is the intercept plus the coefficient on the dummy variable for any particular `id`.

```r
set.seed(123)
dat <- tibble(
  dist = sample(LETTERS[1:10], 1000, replace=TRUE), 
  grade = sample(letters[17:26], 1000, replace=TRUE), 
  id = paste(dist, grade, sep="-"), 
  y = rnorm(1000)
)

mod <- lm(y ~ factor(id), data=dat)
```

Now, let's say we want to use the model to get the mean for any `grade`, here are the `grade`  means of `y`.

```r
dat %>% 
  group_by(grade) %>% 
  summarise(m = mean(y))
# # A tibble: 10 × 2
#  grade       m
#  <chr>   <dbl>
# 1 q     -0.0523
# 2 r     -0.193 
# 3 s     -0.0964
# 4 t      0.0647
# 5 u     -0.161 
# 6 v     -0.0273
# 7 w      0.0390
# 8 x      0.109 
# 9 y     -0.104 
# 10 z      0.146
```

Let's try to use the model estimates to get the `grade` mean of `y` for `grade=z`.  First, let's find out what percentage of observations are in each `id` group containing `grade=z`:

```r
n <- dat %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  tally() %>% 
  filter(str_detect(id, "z$")) %>% 
  mutate(pct = n/sum(n))
n
# # A tibble: 10 × 3
#  id        n    pct
#  <chr> <int>  <dbl>
# 1 A-z      11 0.112 
# 2 B-z      10 0.102 
# 3 C-z      13 0.133 
# 4 D-z       6 0.0612
# 5 E-z      12 0.122 
# 6 F-z       8 0.0816
# 7 G-z       9 0.0918
# 8 H-z      10 0.102 
# 9 I-z       7 0.0714
# 10 J-z     12 0.122
```

We can now collecting the intercept and the `id` values that contain `grade=z`:

```r
ests <- broom::tidy(mod) %>% 
  filter(str_detect(term, "ntercept|z")) %>% 
  mutate(term = gsub("factor\\(id\\)", "", term)) %>% 
  select(1,2) 
ests
# # A tibble: 11 × 2
#   term        estimate
#   <chr>          <dbl>
# 1 (Intercept)  -0.391 
# 2 A-z           0.264 
# 3 B-z           0.572 
# 4 C-z           0.520 
# 5 D-z           0.863 
# 6 E-z           0.774 
# 7 F-z           0.755 
# 8 G-z           0.591 
# 9 H-z           0.0538
# 10 I-z          -0.0657
# 11 J-z           0.951
```

We can then join these data to the percentages from above and replace the percentage for the `intercept` term to 1 because wa want to add the intercept to the weighted average of the group coefficients:

```r
ests <- ests %>% 
  left_join(n %>% rename(term = id)) %>% 
  mutate(pct = ifelse(is.na(pct), 1, pct)) 
ests
# # A tibble: 11 × 4
#   term        estimate     n    pct
#   <chr>          <dbl> <int>  <dbl>
# 1 (Intercept)  -0.391     NA 1     
# 2 A-z           0.264     11 0.112 
# 3 B-z           0.572     10 0.102 
# 4 C-z           0.520     13 0.133 
# 5 D-z           0.863      6 0.0612
# 6 E-z           0.774     12 0.122 
# 7 F-z           0.755      8 0.0816
# 8 G-z           0.591      9 0.0918
# 9 H-z           0.0538    10 0.102 
# 10 I-z          -0.0657     7 0.0714
# 11 J-z           0.951     12 0.122
```

Finally, we can just sum the `estimate` column multiplied by the `pct` column:

```r
ests %>% 
  summarise(m = sum(pct*estimate))
# # A tibble: 1 × 1
#  m
#  <dbl>
# 1 0.146
```

Note that this is exactly the same value that we calculated for the `grade=z` mean from above.  This suggests that we can perfectly recover the `grade` means of `y` by using the `id` coefficients, which means that we cannot estimate the independent effect of `grade` once `id` is already accounted for because of perfect collinearity.

Comment: Another way to show that `grade` can be perfectly predicted from `id` is to regress `grade` on `id` and note that the residual sum of squares (aka deviance) is 0 hence the residuals are all 0 and it is a perfect prediction.  `G <- model.matrix(~ grade + 0, dat); modg <- lm(G ~ factor(id) + 0, dat); deviance(modg)`

Comment: You could also use `x <- model.matrix(y ~ factor(grade) + factor(id) -1, data=dat); eigen(cor(x))$values` and you would see Eigenvalues that are roughly equal to zero.  This also identifies the perfect collinearity.

Comment: Also `lm(y ~ grade + factor(id) + 0, dat)$rank` shows that the rank is 100 which is less than the number of columns (109) so it is not of full rank.

Comment: Easy way to check with package plm directly (esp. for non-statistitions): `plm::detect.lindep(fe)` to check if this is linear dependence after the FE transformation. The help page `?plm::detect.lindep` has an example to better understand the term "linear dependence after FE transformation".

Comment: @Helix123 you should post that as an answer.  That's easier than what we have posted.

Comment: All of these are excellent answers and very well-explained. Thank you! Please correct me if I am wrong. If I really want to know an effect on each grade, I have to filter by grade and run the regression separately without using the dummy variable. Is it correct to do it in this way?

Comment: Sorry for flushing you guys with another comment. I tried with another package, `fixest` and it seems like @DaveArmstrong is correct about this. The model dropped all factors due to the collinearity problem. I would be appreciated it if you could suggest any ways to retrieve the coefficients of these grades. Should I not combine the district and id together? Btw, I am sorry for my strong confidence in the P.S.

Comment: @Kob insofar as the effect of `grade` is the change in the average dependent variable value as `grade` changes controlling for other things, you can do as I did above for each different value of `grade`.  Running the regression models separately by `grade` will not help you recover the coefficients for the `grade` variable.

Comment: Thanks again for your response, @DaveArmstrong! This is very helpful for me. I have one last question. If I use this model (id and time fixed-effect), does it mean my regression has three fixed-effect; district, grade, and year? I am unsure if I can write a coefficient separately between district and grade. I have researched this for several websites, but I have yet to find one. Any ideas/suggestions/ resources on this would be appreciated.

Comment: @Kob not in the traditional sense.  The fixed- effect model does a within-transformation subtracting the group-mean of the variables from each observation's value.  For example, if you were using grade, district and year fixed effects, you would do `grade + district + year` (where each is a factor and you would get dummy variables for each level (-1) of each variable.  Instead, what you're doing here with id would be akin to `grade * district + year` - making an interaction of `grade` and `district`.  I would call this two fixed-effects one on district-grade and one on time.

Comment: @DaveArmstrong That makes much more sense, Dave! Thank you for your explanation of this. I was trying to run the former with `plm`, but it gave me an error. I did some research and many websites said that I should combine these two identities together to run in the `plm`. I found another package called `fixest`. It allows me to run more than two fixed effects at the same time, and I think I will go with this package rather than `plm`.